# local.xml url helpers reference

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, local.xml

I"m new to the magento front, and I need to develop a template for it, but somehow I can't wrap my head around the url helpers in the local.xml...

Is there a reference list for available helpers? Or is there a method how can I track down the available helpers in the magento code?

I was looking at the `top.links` customization options at classyllama.com, but most of the relevant aritcles are outdated, and while the concept works, some of the helpers don't.

Comment: aznim, are you  want to add  new item to toplink using helpers???

Comment: I mainly I have to re-organize and decorate the original links, and the best solution I found is removing and replacing the original links with new ones, but the helper I found for the login/logout buttons at crazyllama don't work. Also, there's a possibility that I'll have to add system function later on, so the helpers would be quite useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the xml `<url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>` simply means that the link will use the helper that can be called by `Mage::helper('customer')` and use the method `getAccountUrl` to get the url used.

Technically you can add any helper here and ever write your own.